# HTML Client side pagination - Cant get dynamically added data

Tags: javascript, pagination, pug

So I'm using a javascript pagination http://en.newinstance.it/2006/09/27/client-side-html-table-pagination-with-javascript/ which works great.. except for when I try to load my dynamically added data (from a getJSON). The issue is that it is checking the table but not finding any results as it is injected into the innerHTML and not "hard-coded" in I guess.

this is the javascript

```
script(type='text/javascript')    
    pager = new Pager('results', 3);
      pager.init();
      pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition');
      pager.showPage(1);
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? I've tried using some of the proper datagrid but I cannot get them to work with my application.

```
$.getJSON( '/getlocations', function( data ) {
        userListData = data;

        // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
        $.each(data, function(){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.name + '" title="Show Details">' + this.name + '</a></td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.information + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.lat + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.lon + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td><button onclick="viewLocationOnMap()">View on map</button></td>';
            tableContent += '<td>In Progress</button></td>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteitem" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

        // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
        $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure whats wrong. But I have a few suggestions.
1. Don't enclose double quotes in single quotes, if you do, try escaping them.
2. I don't see where have declared `tableContent` variable. You must declare it in your `getJson` function and later use in `each` loop so the concatenation works fine.
3. Debug by just adding single line of text and see it gets appeneded fine
4. `each` accepts `index` and `value` as function arguments, so use value instead of `this` while iterating.

Comment: Hi, ok thanks I'll be sure of the double quotes.
2. It all works fine, I've declared it above. nothing is wrong with the concatenation, the table shows perfectly etc It's just the pagenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your `<table>` HTML looks like, I notice that if I tried to initalize the pagination with an empty HTML table i.e. no rows, the browser console will throw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
```

The `paging.js` seems to rely on the fact that the `<tr>` rows exist and are styled with certain CSS classes, namely, `.pg-normal` and `.pg-selected` defined. Anyway, I manage to get your codes to work by:

1. Instantiating the pagination **after** the `<tr>` HTML are appended, and
2. Replace `$('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);` with `$('#result').append(tableContent);` since `result` is the ID of the table used in the initializing the pagination.

Take a look at the stack snippet below or this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/48dxxm6o/):

```js
/*** Javascript ***/
// For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
var data = [
    {id:1, name:'cell1', information:'First Row'},
    {id:2, name:'cell2', information:'Second Row'},
    {id:3, name:'cell3', information:'Third Row'},
    {id:4, name:'cell4', information:'Fourth Row'},
    {id:5, name:'cell5', information:'Fifth Row'},
    {id:6, name:'cell6', information:'Sixth Row'},
    {id:7, name:'cell7', information:'Seventh Row'},
    {id:8, name:'cell8', information:'Eighth Row'},
    {id:9, name:'cell9', information:'Nineth Row'},
];
var tableContent = "";
$.each(data, function(){
    tableContent += '<tr>';
    tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.name + '" title="Show Details">' + this.information + '</a></td>';
    tableContent += '<td><button onclick="viewLocationOnMap()">View on map</button></td>';
    tableContent += '<td>In Progress</button></td>';
    tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteitem" rel="' + this._id + '">Delete</a></td>';
    tableContent += '</tr>';
});

// Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
$('#results').append(tableContent);

// Instantiate pagination after data is available    
pager = new Pager('results', 3);
pager.init();
pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition');
pager.showPage(1);
      
// pagination object codes.
function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function (from, to) {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to) rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    this.showPage = function (pageNumber) {
        if (!this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg' + this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg' + this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }

    this.prev = function () {
        if (this.currentPage > 1) this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function () {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }

    this.init = function () {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1);
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function (pagerName, positionId) {
        if (!this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
        var element = document.getElementById(positionId);
        var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span> | ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++)
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';
        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
}
```

```css
/*** CSS ***/
table {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;    
}

th, td{
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    padding:5px;
}

.pg-normal {
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;    
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.pg-selected {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;        
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Information</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>     
</table>
<div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
```

Comment: wow that is great, I added the pagination code directly under where I appended the table and its picking up the pages etc! Just one quick question, whenever I PRess Prev or Next I'm receiving an "onclick" error, - uncaught TypeErro: undefined is not a function.

This is the line it points to? <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js

Could it be the jquery I'm using is much newer?

edit: just tried a different jquery (the one you have linked, and still the same error)

Comment: I recopied and pasted the four pager lines and it worked...Thankyou so much. have been working on this for an entire day!